# Windows Server 2008 x64: registered dll cannot be loaded

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've registered a COM dll using regsvr32 as I've always used to do, but when the code that uses this dll is fired i get the following exception:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for
>   component with CLSID
>   {E4F35ED2-71B3-4F6D-A4A9-FAA456365819}
>   failed due to the following error:
>   80040154.

I checked the error by id and it says that the dll could not be loaded. I checked the registry and the dll is properly registered - what may be the problem in this case?

Edit: the code is fired by Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)? (Make sure that you get the 64 bit version)

Also, its worth noting that you will only be able to load 32 bit assemblies in a 32 bit process, and 64 bit assemblies in a 64 bit process.

Comment: well it might be the case - if Sharepoint process is 64 bit - and I have to check it

Comment: It probably is, unless you have configured IIS to run web applications on that application pool as 32 bit.  See this blog post on how to do that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx